# Issue with current user editing/deleting in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I currently have an issue where I am trying to set the ability that only the user who created a group may edit or delete a group. I am getting the following error: undefined method `user' for #

I have the following code in my group index controller:

```
  <% @nearby_groups.each do |group| %>
   <h1><%= group.topic %></h1>
   <p><%= group.description %></p>
   <% if current_user.id == group.user.id %>
     <%= link_to "Edit", edit_group_path(group), class: "ui black button" %>
     <%= link_to "Delete", group_path(group), method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Are you Sure?"},
    class: "ui inverted red button " %>
   <% end %>
 <%= link_to "show", group_path(group), class: "ui inverted blue button" %>
<% end %>
```

On my group show page I have the following code:

```
  <h1>The <%= @group.topic %> Group!</h1>
  <p>Description: <em><%= @group.description %></em></p>
  <p>Group Address: <em><%= @group.address %></em></p>
  <p>Group City: <em><%= @group.city %></em></p>
  <p>Group State: <em><%= @group.state %></em></p>
  <% if current_user.id == @group.user.id %>
    <%= link_to "Edit", edit_group_path(), class: "ui black button" %>
    <%= link_to "Delete", group_path(), method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Are you Sure?"},
    class: "ui inverted red button " %>
 <% end %>
```

My groups controller looks like this:

```
  def index 
    @groups = Group.includes(:comments)
  end

  def show
    @group = Group.find(params[:id])
  end
```

Finally, my groups model looks like this:

```
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :collections
  has_many :comments 
  has_many :users, :through => :collections

  validates :topic, presence: true
  validates :description, presence: true, length: { minimum: 10 }
  validates :address, presence: true
  validates :city, presence: true
  validates :address, presence: true

  geocoded_by :address
  after_validation :geocode
end
```

Again, on both my index and show pages for group I get the following error: undefined method `user' for # Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change:

```
<% if current_user.id == @group.user.id %>
```

To:

```
<% if current_user.id == @group.try(:user).try(:id) %>
```

Or to account for `current_user` being `nil` when user is not logged out:

```
<% if current_user and current_user.id == @group.try(:user).try(:id) %>
```

---

Reference:

```
# +try+ calls can be chained:
#
#   @person.try(:spouse).try(:name)
```

via: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/be589a8b01500a4b52a86248458bf57597e568e8/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/try.rb#L16

---

Note: This answer doesn't account for Active Record association issues: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-types-of-associations

---

**Update**

According to your `has_many_through` association, the plural `Group#users` should return an Active Record relation object which looks like an array containing any associated users.

Change to:

```
<% if current_user and @group.users.map {|user| user.id}.include?(current_user.id) %>
```

This type of logic should be moved to the model layer, for example:

```
# app/models/users.rb
class User
  def has_group_access?(group_id)
    Collection.find_by_group_id_and_user_id(group_id, self.id)
  end
end

# app/views/whatevs.html.erb
<% if current_user and current_user.has_group_access?(@group.id) %>
```

---

**Update 2**

If group belongs to user, then change to:

```
<% if current_user and current_user.id == @group.user_id %>
```

Comment: This partly worked-the error messages went away but even with the user who created a group, they cannot edit them. Any solutions?

Comment: I need more info to assess what the issue is. I have a feeling it's an association issue with `has_many_through`. Go into `rails console` from the command line and 1) `@group = Group.find(your_group_id_that_has_); @group.user # => should return a user right?`.  Then 2) `@group.users # => should return all the associated users right?` LMK if 1 and 2 works—I might have a solution for you.

Comment: okay, typing in group = Group.find(1) I get the group id back of 1. However, if I type in group.user 1 I get the rails console error message. Does that help? Let me know what other information you need!

Comment: How about `group.users`?

Comment: with at group.users (the @ is outfront) I get the user who created group id 1 plus all of the information for that user

Comment: @MikeCuddy I updated my answer with an additional solution.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115877/discussion-between-soawesomeman-and-mike-cuddy).

Comment: in chat room @soAwesomeMan